# why does ^" match the less then sign ?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was just going this answer **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277876/4381665)**, and i was just playing arouund with the regex in the answer until i reduced one of the regexs to the following:

```
([^"])
```

And then i add the below string:

```
<img src="/sites/ContentCenter/Graphics/map-al.jpg" alt="map al" style="width&#58;611px;height&#58;262px;" />&#160;<br></p><p><br></p><p>
```

To check against the above regex , **[SEE HERE](https://regex101.com/r/tA4lD4/5)** , now the above regex mathces the `<` of the img tag , why do ? why does `([^"])` match the `<` in the image tag ? can somebody explain ?

Comment: `[^"]` means a character that isn't `"`, so loads of characters will match

Comment: @SmokeyPHP facepalm ! thanks .. :)

Comment: The regex101.com link that you shared even explains this on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

```
([^"])
```

Is a group (`()`) of a character from class *every-character-except-double-quote* so it can match anything except the double quote, even `<`.